# Problema con cronometro de javascript cuando minimizo la ventana del navegador

Tags: javascript, html5

este es mi código para crear un cronómetro, funciona bien, el único problema que me presenta es que cuando minimizo el navegador (cualquier navegador), el cronómetro no sigue contando tiempo.

si vuelvo a maximizar el navegador nuevamente cuenta el tiempo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div class="reloj" id="Horas">00</div>
        <div class="reloj" id="Minutos">:00</div>
        <div class="reloj" id="Segundos">:00</div>
        <div class="reloj" id="Centesimas">:00</div>
        <input type="button" class="boton" id="inicio" value="Start &#9658;" onclick="inicio();">
        <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value="Stop &#8718;" onclick="parar();" disabled>
        <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value="Resume &#8634;" onclick="inicio();" disabled>
        <!-- <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value="Reset &#8635;" onclick="reinicio();" disabled> -->
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var centesimas = 0;
    var segundos = 0;
    var minutos = 0;
    var horas = 0;
    function inicio () {
        control = setInterval(cronometro,10);
        document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
    }
    function parar () {
        clearInterval(control);
        document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
    }
    function reinicio () {
        clearInterval(control);
        centesimas = 0;
        segundos = 0;
        minutos = 0;
        horas = 0;
        Centesimas.innerHTML = ":00";
        Segundos.innerHTML = ":00";
        Minutos.innerHTML = ":00";
        Horas.innerHTML = "00";
        document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
    }
    function cronometro () {
        if (centesimas < 99) {
            centesimas++;
            if (centesimas < 10) { centesimas = "0"+centesimas }
            Centesimas.innerHTML = ":"+centesimas;
        }
        if (centesimas == 99) {
            centesimas = -1;
        }
        if (centesimas == 0) {
            segundos ++;
            if (segundos < 10) { segundos = "0"+segundos }
            Segundos.innerHTML = ":"+segundos;
        }
        if (segundos == 59) {
            segundos = -1;
        }
        if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0) ) {
            minutos++;
            if (minutos < 10) { minutos = "0"+minutos }
            Minutos.innerHTML = ":"+minutos;
        }
        if (minutos == 59) {
            minutos = -1;
        }
        if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0)&&(minutos == 0) ) {
            horas ++;
            if (horas < 10) { horas = "0"+horas }
            Horas.innerHTML = horas;
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pues tu problema no es JavaScript, los navegadores para no consumir recursos de la maquina deciden no cargarla con funciones JavaScript. de hecho puedes abrir una pestaña escribir una url y cambiarla el navegador no te actualizara la pagina hasta que este activa

Comment: he probado tu codigo en mozilla firefox 64.0 Centos 7 y funciona de maravilla... no se pausa el cronometro...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/namx2z7q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal parece algunos navegadores (como Google Chrome) cambian su comportamiento cuando están corriendo en el background (como al ser minimizados) y solamente permiten timeOuts no menores a 1.000 milisegundos. O sea que puedes o bien cambiar el valor  de la variable `control` en la función `inicio()`, así:

```
control = setInterval(cronometro,1000);
```

... con lo que perderías la funcionalidad de los valores menores a 1 segundo, o bien usar [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Usando_web_workers)

[Aquí te dejo un link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) que explica a mi entender con mayor claridad cómo funcionan los web workers, como para que puedas adaptar más fácilmente el código de este ejemplo a tu cronómetro.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo leí y muy interesante ese tema, te pregunto alguna vez has trabajado con este tema?, intente aplicarlo a mi código del cronómetro y no logro que funcione...